# SVN Sync Error between master and mirror servers

Tags: svn, svnsync

I have two servers as master and slave for mirroring the repo for backup purpose.
Everythign was working fine untill yesterday when the sync started giving the following error.

> Could not read status line: Connection reset by peer
>   (http://1.1.1.1)

I am using subversion 1.6 with apache 2.2.15. The SVN is enabled on http. The sync starts for few seconds and then throws the above error.

please help me fix this issue. Ask me if you need more information about my svn setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Subversion 1.6 anymore. Subversion 1.7 and older is very outdated and not supported. Use Subversion 1.9 or at least 1.8. There is a chance that the problem will be solved after upgrading Subversion.

Update: current version is SVN 1.14.